# I'm getting an IllegalStateException: Already connected and I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, cookies, illegalstateexception

So I'm trying to write a program which connects to a site and pulls data from the source code. Whenever I call this method, once it reaches the line `connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);` it doesn't proceed any further and spits out "IllegalStateException: Already connected". I'm trying to cycle through 123 different URL's so the URL changes each time the method is called, so I'm not too sure why it's telling me it's already connected when I'm attempting to reconnect to a different URL. I've tried searching everywhere for a solution and cannot find one. Can any of you help? Thanks!

```
private void getUrlData(String u, String championName) throws IOException {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Other Stuff/Champion Data Test.txt"));
        out.write(championName);
        out.newLine();

        URL url = new URL(u);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36");
        connection.connect();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());

        String inputLine;
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            inputLine = in.nextLine();
            if(inputLine.contains("stat-label")) {
                out.write(in.nextLine());
                in.nextLine();
                in.nextLine();
                out.write(" " + in.nextLine());
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you call this mehtod?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, but me solving this problem aroused new problems. The problem was me using the method `connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie")`.